# Export-import Kibana [7.4] objects through saved_objects api

Tags: python, kibana, kibana-7

I am trying to move index patterns, visualizations and dashboards from one Kibana to another. They are running in separate dockers, listening to different ports. In the saved_objects API there are, import and export. Naively assuming that what `export` produces can be consumed by `import` I tried the code below:

```
import requests as req

header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'kbn-xsrf': 'true'}

request_json_index_pattern = '''
{
  "type": "index-pattern"
}
'''

index_patterns = req.post(kibana_host+':5601/api/saved_objects/_export',
                    data=request_json_index_pattern,
                    headers = header,
                    auth = (elastic_user, elastic_password))


res = req.post(kibana_host+':5602/api/saved_objects/_import',
                    data=index_patterns.content,
                    headers = header,
                    auth = (elastic_user, elastic_password))



print(res.content)
```

But all I get is

```
{'statusCode': 415, 'error': 'Unsupported Media Type', 'message': 'Unsupported Media Type'}
```

All that, notwithstanding that `index_patterns.content` is a well-formatted ndjson– I can parsed it with `ndjson.loads`.

What am I missing?

(Btw, my source Kibana instance is 7.3.1 while the target is 7.4.0. Can that be the problem?)

Comment: I also saw that `{"statusCode":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Unsupported Media Type"}` error when I tried to query Kibana while it was not fully setup, eg still in degraded mode. I would recommend to check the Kibana logs for more details in such situation.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this myself.  The `_import` API requires newline delimited json (ndjson), not json.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api-import.html#_examples_3

A slightly hacky work-around that I found is to use the dashboards import api: `/api/kibana/dashboards/import`.  It seems to import all saved objects types (not just dashboards).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this is how i solved:

```
url="" # your kibana host + path 
# i.e kibana_host+':5602/api/saved_objects/_import
# in your question

params=None # or your params
username = "" # kibana username
password = "" # kibana password

# currently min requires headers are: "kbn-xsrf" - set to anything
# in future you may need: Content-Type: application/x-ndjson
headers = {"kbn-xsrf": "true"}

# json = ## your json object
# assuming you have a json object - you need to convert it to a string and format as ndjson

# removed all newlines from the string, then add a couple to the end
# i also removed spaces too, but i dont think this is required

data = json_dumps(json).replace('\n', '').replace(" ", "")+"\n\n"

# if you dont have a json object and just have a string, which may be an ndjson string 
# i.e. {}{}{} or {}\n{}\n{}\n
#  - remove the json_dumps

# myString = ## your string var
# data = myString.replace('\n', '').replace(" ", "")+"\n\n"

# now make it a file - you need to define a filename with an ndjson extension - or it will get rejected

files = {'file': ('request.ndjson', data) }    

response = requests.post(url=url, params=params, files=files, 
                            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), 
                            headers=headers)
```

Obviously you will need to add the relevant imports required, as a starter:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
from json import dumps as json_dumps, loads as json_loads
```